# Use custom button for Google Sign-in

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, button, customization

I'm working on adding Google Sign-in to the web site (Anguar 9) and found that with the new version of Google Identity Services I'm not able to use custom button (I need it to meet several project requirements). A link that shows how to use custom button is targeted to the deprecated version. So, at the moment I've implemented it using 'https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js'.
Are you going to add support of custom buttons, similar to this article - https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button#building_a_button_with_a_custom_graphic

Comment: Did you ever find a way around this?